# RubyMine, Vagrant, RVM

Tags: rvm, vagrant, rubymine

I'm on OS X host where I have RubyMine (7) and last Vagrant installed. I've prepared shell script for provision my vagrant box with RVM, ruby (2.1.2), bundle my project, run all tests, manually start server. Everything seems fine.
Now I want to make RubyMine works with RVM ruby from vagrant guest (run server, specs with debugging). I've added remote ruby SDK, point them to RVM ruby binary (http://prntscr.com/5i6g1f). But when I try to start development server, I've receive message that no rails installed in SDK. But it is installed via bundle, I can run server manually from guest.
Please, advice me how can I tell RubyMine where to find gems inside Vagrant with RVM?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When using RVM, the path to remote SDK should not point to the binary but rather to the ruby gems directory.

In your case, for instance, the correct path should be:

```
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
```

Note that it should point to the DIRECTORY not the executable!

To find the directory simply run:

```
$ rvm gemdir
```

Then copy and paste the result.

Comment: Worked for me. This should be marked as the right answer.

Comment: Thanks so muc for this incormation, RDP. How did you find this out? I've dug through the documentation for last couple of hours and only found the answer here.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Configuring+Remote+Interpreters

Answer (score 0):

change the path to `ruby`

from: `/path/to/rvm/rubies/ruby-version/bin/ruby`

to: `/path/to/rvm/wrappers/ruby-version/ruby`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but no luck :( I've tried to delete old remote SDK and create new one as you advised - same result. RubyMine can't see any gems.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem if any rbenv user face then type "which ruby" without quotes in terminal it will point to the shims folder of rbenv but select versions folder and select irb instead of ruby as rubymine need irb (ruby interpreter) instead of ruby binary.